# Centering Scaled asp.net Image in web page

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I looked at all answers but none of them worked for me !!

I have image `<image>` in my webpage that need to be in the center
I used position:absolute to scale the image to match the size of the window/page

but when I do this the image start from position 0,0

how can I center it horizontally ?

```
<image id="imgImage" runat="server" style="padding: 0; display: block; margin: 0 auto; position: absolute;
    max-height: 100%; max-width: 100%;"></image>
```

Comment: There is no such element as `image` in the HTML standard.

Comment: @feeela sorry its asp.net image

Comment: Then you should post the rendered HTML output if you have an HTML/CSS question. Post the ASP code if you have an ASP question…

Comment: Using `position: absolute;` you will have to position the image 50% from the top and left, then offsetting the the image via negative margin equal to the images height/width in order for it to be in the center. Also make sure the container elements position is set to `relative`.

But a more pleasant solution is to use flexbox for the container and using `justify-content: center`